# Missing Operand

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

i am having an issue with this code here, its giving me a message "missing operand" right after the "call :getCurrentDate" syntax. i have made sure to check that i have everything to set the vars, and im pretty sure i set the vars correctly, yet i still cant figure out why its giving me the message "missing operand".

here is my code:

```
@echo off
title File Transfer
color 0f
set /a count=0
set /a fullDate=0
goto collect_dirs

:collect_dirs (
    if exist "L:\reports" (
        echo Source Folder Found!
        echo.
        timeout /nobreak /t 1 > nul
    ) else (
        echo Unable to Find Source Folder...
        timeout /nobreak /t 2 > nul
        echo.
        echo The application is now quitting.
        timeout /nobreak /t 3 > nul
        exit
    )
    if exist "C:\Common\Credit Reports" (
        echo Destination Folder Found!
        timeout /nobreak /t 1 > nul
    ) else (
        echo Unable to Find Destination Folder...
        timeout /nobreak /t 2 > nul
        echo.
        echo The application is now quitting.
        timeout /nobreak /t 3 > nul
        exit
    )
    goto move_files
)

:move_files (
    cls 
    call :getPrevDate
    cd "L:\reports"
    echo ####################
    echo #   Moving Files   #
    echo ####################
    echo.
    for /R "L:\reports" %%f in (ABC_%fullDate%_*.pdf) do (
        xcopy "%%f" "C:\Common\Credit Reports"
        call :amt
    )
    goto complete
)

:getPrevDate (
    for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do (
        set /a fullDate=%%g%%e%%f
        set /a fullDate-=1
    )
    exit /b
)

:amt (
    set /a count+=1
    exit /b
)

:complete (
    cls
    echo #################################
    echo #  Files Transfering Complete!  #
    echo #################################
    echo #                               #
    echo #  %count% Files Transfered     
    echo #                               #
    echo #################################
    echo #     Press Any Key to Exit     #
    echo #################################
    pause > nul
)
```

could you please help me find out why and explain to my why its happening, i would be very thankful :)

Comment: There is no `:getCurrentDate` in the code you posted. Did you mean `:getPrevDate`?

Comment: I would highly recommend you not surround the code after your labels in parentheses.

Comment: And that labelled section is unlikely to work for you anyhow. To begin with the variable `%date%` format is User/PC/Locale dependent, which means you cannot guarantee the positions of year, month and day, my `%%g%%e%%f` would be `022021`. You also cannot expect to be able to subtract `1` to get the date for the previous day. What happens for instance, if today was 1st February 2021, `%fullDate%` would expand to `20210201` and then `20210200`, which is clearly not the correct date `20210131`, and things would get worse for lets say `20210101`, which instead of `20201231`, would read `20210100`.

Comment: I have to agree with @Compo, but would add you cannot rely on the string-length of the elements either, or on the presence of the dayname `%%d` which would not appear on my machine. I'd try inserting a line `echo "%%g%%e%%f"& pause` directly after the `for /f ... %%d ...` line, which may reveal something of significance - and I'd suggest that it's likely that your `date` format contains `-` which would make the following `set/a` statement resolve as, for instance, `20212-15-` for Feb 15th 2021. This would explain the `missing operand` problem as there's no final term.